# Xbox Series S NVME M2 drive doesnt work. How to replace the SSD NVME M2 Drive?

Tags: hardware, xbox-series-x-series-s

I bought another NVME m2 drive from ebay that is 512GB and did a clone from the Series S nvme drive using Macrium Reflect. And the system would just turn off when I press the power button. Anyone have this issue?

Putting back the original nvme m2 works, but I'm trying to replace it because there is an issue with the original M2 causing games to lag and freeze. Are the nvme m2 drives married to the Xbox Series motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a Series S or X SSD NVME M2 to another Series S or X drive works, but if cloning to another non-xbox series drive doesnt work.

It seems the individual SSDs are not married to the motherboard but there might be something with the controller on the SSD that the console looks for. So in order to get it to work again, you need to find another Xbox Series model drive, which is quite expensive.